# how to Calculate speed and distance traveled in Java

Tags: java

how do you write a program that prompts for and reads integer values for speed and distance traveled, then prints the time required for the trip as a floating point result in java using eclipse

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
public class Lab3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int time = 0;
        int distance = 0;
        int speed = distance/time;
        float fval = speed * time;
        double dval = distance/speed;
        String message;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Avaerage Speed: ");
        message = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You Entered: \"" + message + "\"");
        System.out.println("Your Total Speed is: ");
```

Comment: what is the code you have written so far ?

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Lab3 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 
  int time = 0;
  int distance = 0;
  int speed = distance/time;  
  float fval = speed * time;
  double dval = distance/speed;
  
  
  
  String message;
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please Enter Your Avaerage Speed: ");
  message = scan.nextLine();
  
  System.out.println("You Entered: \"" + message + "\"");
 
  System.out.println("Your Total Speed is: ");

Comment: it's crashing. My console isn't able to take data or input

Comment: Edit your question to include your code and the error.  Don't paste a wall of code in comments.  Also, please read the **How To Ask** article before posting again.

Comment: Not sure if I'm inputting my variable properly

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

1. You haven't finished your code.
2. You need a closing `}` for each `{`.
3. Include the value you want to output here:

   ```
      System.out.println("Your Total Speed is: ");
   ```

   Hint: the string concatenation operator is .... ?
4. Hint: you can't calculate the speed before you know what the distance and time values are.  `speed = distance/time;` is an assignment statement, not an equation.

---

> it's crashing. My console isn't able to take data or input

1. The code you showed us doesn't compile.  You can't run it ... so it can't be crashing.  Hint: show us the real code.  All of it.
2. If it is crashing, then there must be a stacktrace.  The stacktrace contains important information that will help us (and you) identify the cause of the problem. Put all important information into the Question.  Use the Edit button.

My guess is that an `ArithmeticException` is being thrown here

```
      int speed = distance/time;
```

because you are dividing by zero.  You are dividing by zero, because on the line before you set `time` to zero.  Explicitly.

Please read what I wrote above ("4. Hint: ...") about not doing calculations before you have the inputs.

Comment: ok I'm a little confused. how to i declare my variable. what was wrong with what I had below:                                                                                           int time = 0;
        int distance = 0;
        int speed = distance/time;
        float fval = speed * time;
        double dval = distance/speed;

Comment: Please see "4. Hint: ..." and my last updates.

Comment: Stephen, that is a very well written and descriptive answer to such a poor question

Answer (score -1):

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please Enter speed: ");
        int speed = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please Enter distance: ");
        int distance = in.nextInt();
        float time = (float)distance / speed;
        System.out.println("Your time is: " + time);
    }
}
```

Comment: One quick question if you don't mind. How would I write a program that reads values representing a time duration in hours, minutes, and seconds and then prints the equivalent total number of seconds. (For example, 1 hour, 28 minutes, and 42 seconds is equivalent to 5322 seconds.)

Comment: does this help ? http://www.coderanch.com/t/515273/java/java/convert-hours-minutes-seconds-seconds

Comment: But you didn't explain why what he wrote originally was wrong.  That is far more important than a solution ... if the OP is to learn from doing this homework exercise.  His followup question and your comment is another case in point.  He is not going to learn to program by copying / borrowing from other peoples' code.

Comment: @Stephen i agree. OP, you declared 2 variables, time and distance and initialized them to 0. Then you try to divide them both, which gives you DivideByZero error as your denominator is equal to zero. you first want to accept data from the user and then just plug them in your formula to get the answer.